# Hanging indentation of section number to the left of the margin

Tags: sectioning, formatting, numbering, indentation

Do you know how I get this:

[image]

To look like this:

[image]

Comment: MWE please, we don't know what packages you might be already using.

Comment: @Hector If you accept an answer, may be you'd like to vote it up! (upper arrow above the tick of accept)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `\@seccntformat`. The original definition in `latex.ltx` reads:

```latex
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
```

You can put that inside `\llap`:

```latex
\def\@seccntformat#1{\llap{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}}
```

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\llap{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Here some text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the `titlesec` package (see the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) for details on the commands used).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-6ex}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Here some text
\end{document}
```

[image]